# Puting the remainder of the rows in a long table in the next page(s) in IEEETran document class

Tags: tables, longtable, ieeetran, journal-publishing

I have a long table with around 25 rows and my documnet class in IEEETran. Unfortunately, some of the remainder of the rows are hidden in the bottom of the page and I need the remainder to be shown in the next page(s). How I can do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs, longtable}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table*}
\caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{8}{C} c @{}}
\toprule
\hline
Model & year & input & Backbone & Architecture  & Dataset(s) 
 \\ 
\hline
Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\
\hline
Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\
\hline
Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Update:
> Using the solution introduced by @koleygr causes to have a empty column in the previous page before the table as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really care about a `floating` environment and you are able to place it after a specific page etc just add the package : `ltablex` and replace `caption` with `capt-of` (`caption` package is actually incompatible with your class).

Then place the `tabularx` environment between `\clearpage\onecolumn` and `\clearpage\twocolumn` and replace `\caption` with `\captionof{table}`.

Final: replace the `_` with `\_` whenever seen in text mode:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,  tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage\onecolumn
\captionof{table}{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{8}{C} c @{}}
\toprule
\hline
Model & year & input & Backbone & Architecture  & Dataset(s) 
 \\ 
\hline
Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\
\hline
Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\
\hline
Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\clearpage\twocolumn
\end{document}
```

PS: I had also to clear many duplicated packages from loading

**EDIT:**

Not sure if this way will be accepted from possible publishers since the template is now used as `onecolumn` and I use `multicol` package to add the two-column option.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,  tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{8}{C} c @{}}
\toprule
\hline
Model & year & input & Backbone & Architecture  & Dataset(s) 
 \\ 
\hline
Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\
\hline
Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\
\hline
Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
 Model\_abc & 2022 & RGB Image, Depth Map, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & CCN & Custom  & Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3 
 \\ \hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the solution. How I can add a section that at the bottom of the table that is in the next page, to be written 'The table is continued'?

Comment: The question is updated based on your introduced solution.

Comment: Another problem is that if the long table occupies n pages, the number of the next table in the document is n+1. In my case, my first long table occupies two pages but the number of the next table in the table is 3 instead of two. How I can fix it?

Comment: @Edited. Didn't really understand your last problem. Good luck!